# Solving a linear system of equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

$$\begin{cases} 3x - 2y + z = 8 \\
 4x - y + 3z = -1\\
5x + y + 2z = -1 \end{cases}$$

Form two equations with *y* elimanted.

It would be really helpful too see what you guys wrote.

Comment: This strikes me as bizarre:  Why not just solve the system of linear equations as usual, and write x=[solution for x] and z=[solution for z] as your two equations?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** just subtract equation $(2)$ from $(3)$ and add to equation $(1)$ to get your $x$.

Answer (score 1):

You could solve one of the three equations for $y$ (I recommend the second or the third), then substitute that into the other two equations (don't forget to simplify by gathering like terms).

Answer (score 1):

Add the second and third equations.  Then add the first equation to twice the third equation.